# Java Project architecture

Tags: java

Can anybody please explain the basic architecture of the project folder of a java project? I know it contains subfolders such as bin for binaries, src for source files, lib for external libraries but I would like to know the specific functions performed by files such as build.xml, project.xml, .project, build.properties?

Comment: Those files aren't specific to Java but to an IDE or build tool. (I'm guessing NetBeans or Ant going by the names, although `.project` looks like Eclipse.) Start with the documentation of the tools you're working on the project with. As far as the JDK is concerned the high-level project layout is entirely arbitrary.

Comment: @millimoose - s/arbitrary/irrelevant/ ... is what you mean I think.

Comment: @StephenC I think I had "can be chosen/set up arbitrarily" in mind and it came out wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on what tools you are using. For example:

- If you are using **Maven**, for example, your project should have a
  `pom.xml` in the root directory and should normally follow the [Maven
  Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).
- If you are using **Ant** then you should have a `build.xml`.
- `.project` is a private file used by **Eclipse** to store
  project-specific configuration information.

You actually have a reasonable amount of flexibility in how you configure your projects, but going crazy is a bad idea because it will just confuse other people and make your tool setup more difficult. My normal advice is to follow the Maven directory layout - it's the closest thing to a standard.

Comment: And, `build.properties` is commonly used with Ant `build.xml` files for project customization. For example, if the project uses and builds a database, the database URL might be stored in that file.  In fact, many open-source projects come with a `build.properties.sample` file that the developer is expected to copy and modify for his project instance.